# Extract width of BMP image in c

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

I am a beginner programmer and trying to learn image processing in c and found some tutorials but I am stuck at a line ( which is responsible for extracting *width* ) 
`int width = *(int*)&header[18];` 
I am unable to understand above syntax .
Can anyone explain in brief ?

Comment: That code uses a magic constant, 18. In my opinion, you are better off finding and looking at an example that uses the proper structs for accessing structured file information like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int width = *(int*)&header[18];
```

Assuming `header` is of type `char*` or `char[]`, piece for piece:

```
header[18]
```

→ get element 18 of `header`

```
&header[18]
```

→ get address of element 18 of `header`

```
(int*)&header[18]
```

→ cast address of element 18 of `header` to pointer to `int`

```
*(int*)&header[18]
```

→ get contents of that pointer to `int`.

---

The values in a BMP file are stored [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian). Hence, this code will work on a little-endian platform only. A more general code would look like this:

```
int width
  = (unsigned)(unsigned char)header[18]
  | (unsigned)(unsigned char)header[19] << 8
  | (unsigned)(unsigned char)header[20] << 16
  | (unsigned)(unsigned char)header[21] << 24;
```

The `int width` is now composed out of individual bytes shifted to their according position. This should work on every endianess.

Comment: Thnx :) Now I am able to understand

Comment: I have one doubt , you wrote at last "get contents" so why we can't get content directly like ` char var=header[18]` .. Is it possible ? Sorry if it is dumb question

Comment: @Aux You didn't mention the type of `header` but I'm quite sure it is `char []` or `char*`. In both cases, `header[18]` returns a `char` (on Intel platforms a type with 8 bit). After, casting the `&header[18]` (which has type `char*`) to `int*`, the de-referencing ("contents operator") provides an `int` (on Intel platforms a type with 32 bit).

Comment: yes it is `char header[54]` in declaration . but why it is type of char ? It is because header information of bmp is in char ?

Comment: @Aux It is of type `char` to make individual bytes addressable. Consider the following counter example: `int header[54];` provides 54 `int`s. Assuming that `int` has 32 bits = 4 bytes these would be 216 bytes - probably too long. In C, pointer arithmetic considers the pointee type, also. Hence, `header[18]` would return the element 18 which starts at byte 18 * 4 = 72. Wrong offset (according to BMP doc.) Note, that in an `int` array, the byte 18 is not addressable at all (not as an address of an element). Element 4 starts at byte 16, next at byte 20.

Comment: Now you cleared my doubt and now I am able to understand that why it is `char header[]` instead of `int header[]` now I am very close to fully understand BMP image. So `header[18]` will give byte 18 but what about 19 20 and 21 byte ? I mean , 19,20 and 21 byte were automatically accessed ? As I know 18 to 21 byte is for width so we dont need to get content from 19 20 and 21 byte also ?